# Indexes missing in Sitecore Indexing Manager

Tags: solr

During the process of upgrading to Sitecore 9.1, I configured Solr indexes, and they show up in dashboard but not showing up in Sitecore indexing manager. Any suggestions/advice?

The crawling log shows this warning:
[image: Log file contents]

Comment: Do the indexes show up in the `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` config?

Answer (score 5):

So, the reason why the solr cores didn't show up in sitecore indexing manager was there was  a naming mismatch between the cores defined in sitecore config vs the cores in Solr Dashboard.
We added a solrsetting patch config to provide the accurate names for the cores to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if Sitecore can't connect to Solr. Verify that Solr is functional, and connectivity is functional between the Sitecore server and the Solr server.

Also ensure that you have followed the appropriate setup instructions for your version of Sitecore (9.1 linked below):

[Walkthrough: Setting up Solr (Sitecore 9.1)](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/walkthrough--setting-up-solr.html)

Comment: This was the same thing that happened in my situation. Solr was not started, but the website was trying to start up and could not find it. Then Solr was started and the site was functioning again, however, the Index Manager showed no indexes available. The simple solution in my case was to just recycle the app pool to restart the web application. This can be done in IIS or simply update the timestamp on the `Web.config` in the root of the site. Go to a web browser and hit the site again. It will take slightly longer the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Me too had same issue.I was make sure everthing in place such as Solr connectivity, proper Index names. But in my case I did below solution to fix the issue.

**Below configuration caused the issue in my case:** (notice the forward slash at end)

```
<add name="solr.search" connectionString="https://<solr server domain URL>:8983/solr/" />
```

**Solution:**

**After removed the forward slash at the end of URL, working like champ.**

```
<add name="solr.search" connectionString="https://<solr server domain URL>:8983/solr" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue that no indexes are shown in the Sitecore indexing manager. I verified the Solr console and all the cores were loading fine there. I have identified after some time that `ContentSearch.Enabled` was set to *false* in `Sitecore.ContentSearch.config` . Changed this setting to true and tried connecting the indexes. it started coming.

Basically, Just go to this path, *`<cm_root>\App_Config\Sitecore\ContentSearch\Sitecore.ContentSearch.config`* and search this setting and make sure this is *true*.

```
<setting name="ContentSearch.Enabled" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have already made all the verification in previously posted answers and you still cant see the indexes in Sitecore Indexing Manager, I have an additional point to make. If you are on SolrCloud and your index configuration had entries for Aliases, then make sure those Aliases are present in the Solr. If not, the indexes wont appear in Sitecore Indexing Manager. In such a scenario, logs will have error like `Alias can not be found`

Answer (score 0):

I found that during my install of Sitecore 10.1, and Solr 8.4.0, my first install failed because I had tried installing it with the Assistant GUI while only having partial admin rights on my windows account, in Windows 11.

This seems to have caused some faulty data to be created in my index folders that were in `C:\Solr\solr-8.4.0\server\solr\`, and further attempts at fully setting up Sitecore and Solr kept failing until I did these 2 steps, after getting FULL admin rights from my IT dept:

1. Rename all the index solr folder names to match the default naming scheme of sitecore. For example, if you have folders like `sc101_core_index` and `sc101_testing_index`, rename them to be `sitecore_core_index`, `sitecore_testing_index`, and so on.
2. If you see this error `["sitecore_xxx_index: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher"]` - Make sure the solr service isn't running (stop it first), then delete the files in the corresponding `sitecore_xxx_index/data/index` folder, to force it to recreate its index files, and then start the solr service backup.

After doing those 2 steps, I was able to see all my indexes in the "Populate Solr Managed Schema" and "Indexing Manager" screens.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use the default index name `sitecore_~`, you can rename the folders to match the names of your local sitecore DBs that you're connecting to, so they match the names of these `~_index` folders, leaving on the _index part at the end for each.
Then you must also change the `id` value in the `<index>` tags in all these config files to match index folder names, and some also have a `<param desc="core">xxx</param>` value that needs changing. All 11 files are listed under step 5 [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/platform-administration-and-architecture/walkthrough--setting-up-solr.html#configure-sitecore-to-work-with-solr), plus these ones below:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\ContentSearch.Azure\Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Index.Core.ExcludeFields.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\ContentSearch.Azure\Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Index.Master.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\ContentSearch.Azure\Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Index.Master.ExcludeFields.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\ContentSearch.Azure\Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Index.Web.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\ContentSearch.Azure\Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Index.Web.ExcludeFields.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\ContentSearch\Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Core.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\ContentSearch\Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Master.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\ContentSearch\Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Web.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\ContentTesting\Sitecore.ContentTesting.Azure.IndexConfiguration.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\ContentTesting\Sitecore.ContentTesting.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\ContentTesting\Sitecore.ContentTesting.Solr.IndexConfiguration.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\ContentTesting\Sitecore.Personalization.Azure.IndexConfiguration.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\ContentTesting\Sitecore.Personalization.Solr.IndexConfiguration.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\EmailExperience\Sitecore.EmailExperience.ContentManagement.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\ExperienceForms\Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Azure.IndexConfiguration.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\ExperienceForms\Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Solr.IndexConfiguration.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\FederatedExperienceManager\Sitecore.FXM.Azure.DomainsSearch.Index.Master.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\FederatedExperienceManager\Sitecore.FXM.Azure.DomainsSearch.Index.Web.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\FederatedExperienceManager\Sitecore.FXM.Solr.DomainsSearch.Index.Master.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\FederatedExperienceManager\Sitecore.FXM.Solr.DomainsSearch.Index.Web.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.Assets\Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.MarketingAssets.Repositories.Azure.Index.Master.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.Assets\Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.MarketingAssets.Repositories.Azure.Index.Web.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.Assets\Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.MarketingAssets.Repositories.Solr.Index.Master.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.Assets\Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.MarketingAssets.Repositories.Solr.Index.Web.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.Operations.xMgmt\Sitecore.Marketing.Azure.Index.Master.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.Operations.xMgmt\Sitecore.Marketing.Azure.Index.Web.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.Operations.xMgmt\Sitecore.Marketing.Solr.Index.Master.config
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc101\App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.Operations.xMgmt\Sitecore.Marketing.Solr.Index.Web.config
```

Restart solr service.

You can manually restart Solr with these admin PowerShell commands. Match the install path to your own Solr install.You may need to install nssm if you don't already have it:

```
PSH:\>  C:\Solr\solr-8.4.0\bin\solr.cmd stop -all
/** check both of these to confirm its stopped properly first **/
PSH:\>  C:\Solr\solr-8.4.0\bin\solr.cmd status solr-8.4.0
PSH:\>  C:\Solr\solr-8.4.0\bin\nssm.exe status solr-8.4.0
/** forcefully start up the solr service **/
PSH:\>  C:\Solr\solr-8.4.0\bin\nssm.exe start solr-8.4.0 -f -p 8983
/** check both statuses again to confirm its started running, which may take 10-30 seconds. **/
```

Restart app pool, IIS.

Now your custom named indexes should show up in the index manager screens.