# Sitecore indexing manager is empty without showing indexes

Tags: solr, sitecore-client, indexing, lucene

**Issue:**
Sitecore Indexing manager not listing any indexes and got the below error in crawling logs.

**About the application architecture:**
We are using Sitecore 9.2 which hosted in On Premises as scaled environments. We have single Solr box which also hosted in on Premises.

**Crawling log:**
[image]

**Have referred more articles. Following is the one which is more relevant.**
[Indexes missing in Sitecore Indexing Manager](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16138/indexes-missing-in-sitecore-indexing-manager)

**Have tried the below steps so far: But no luck.**

1.Checked the connectivity between Sitecore server and Solr using ping and telnet. Working fine

2.Verified indexes in showconfig.aspx. All indexes are listed.

3.Verified the name of the indexes between the Solr admin panel and Sitecore custom index config
files. Both are same.

4.Checked the Solr URL status. Working fine with SSL without certificate errors

5.Restarted Solr service and restated Sitecore application app pool

**Error in Solr admin panel:**

[image]

When checked in Solr log, got below error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:2128) ~[solr-core-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0 b5bf70b7e32d7ddd9742cc821d471c5fabd4e3df - jimczi - 2018-09-18 13:07:55]
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:2248) ~[solr-core-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0 b5bf70b7e32d7ddd9742cc821d471c5fabd4e3df - jimczi - 2018-09-18 13:07:55]
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initSearcher(SolrCore.java:1097) ~[solr-core-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0 b5bf70b7e32d7ddd9742cc821d471c5fabd4e3df - jimczi - 2018-09-18 13:07:55]
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:986) ~[solr-core-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0 b5bf70b7e32d7ddd9742cc821d471c5fabd4e3df - jimczi - 2018-09-18 13:07:55]
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:869) ~[solr-core-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0 b5bf70b7e32d7ddd9742cc821d471c5fabd4e3df - jimczi - 2018-09-18 13:07:55]
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1138) ~[solr-core-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0 b5bf70b7e32d7ddd9742cc821d471c5fabd4e3df - jimczi - 2018-09-18 13:07:55]
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.index.IndexNotFoundException: no segments* file found in LockValidatingDirectoryWrapper(NRTCachingDirectory(MMapDirectory@D:\KPSolr\solr-7.5.0\server\solr\_master_index\data\index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@4a0523a2; maxCacheMB=48.0 maxMergeSizeMB=4.0)): files: [_5ki.dii, _5ki.dim, _5ki.fdt, _5ki.fdx, _5ki.fnm, _5ki.nvd, _5ki.nvm, _5ki.si, _5ki_6.liv, _5ki_Lucene50_0.doc, _5ki_Lucene50_0.pos, _5ki_Lucene50_0.tim, _5ki_Lucene50_0.tip, _5ki_Lucene70_0.dvd, _5ki_Lucene70_0.dvm, _5oh.dii, _5oh.dim, _5oh.fdt, _5oh.fdx, _5oh.fnm, _5oh.nvd, _5oh.nvm, _5oh.si, _5oh_1.liv, _5oh_Lucene50_0.doc, _5oh_Lucene50_0.pos, _5oh_Lucene50_0.tim, _5oh_Lucene50_0.tip, _5oh_Lucene70_0.dvd, _5oh_Lucene70_0.dvm, _5vm.dii, _5vm.dim, _5vm.fdt, _5vm.fdx, _5vm.fnm, _5vm.nvd, _5vm.nvm, _5vm.si, _5vm_Lucene50_0.doc, _5vm_Lucene50_0.pos, _5vm_Lucene50_0.tim, _5vm_Lucene50_0.tip, _5vm_Lucene70_0.dvd, _5vm_Lucene70_0.dvm, _5w3.dii, _5w3.dim, _5w3.fdt, _5w3.fdx, _5w3.fnm, _5w3.nvd, _5w3.nvm, _5w3.si, _5w3_1.liv, _5w3_Lucene50_0.doc, _5w3_Lucene50_0.pos, _5w3_Lucene50_0.tim, _5w3_Lucene50_0.tip, _5w3_Lucene70_0.dvd, _5w3_Lucene70_0.dvm, _5wc.dii, _5wc.dim, _5wc.fdt, _5wc.fdx, _5wc.fnm, _5wc.nvd, _5wc.nvm, _5wc.si, _5wc_Lucene50_0.doc, _5wc_Lucene50_0.pos, _5wc_Lucene50_0.tim, _5wc_Lucene50_0.tip, _5wc_Lucene70_0.dvd, _5wc_Lucene70_0.dvm, write.lock]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:839) ~[lucene-core-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0 b5bf70b7e32d7ddd9742cc821d471c5fabd4e3df - jimczi - 2018-09-18 13:01:13]
    at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.<init>(SolrIndexWriter.java:124) ~[solr-core-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0 b5bf70b7e32d7ddd9742cc821d471c5fabd4e3df - jimczi - 2018-09-18 13:07:55]
    at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.create(SolrIndexWriter.java:97) ~[solr-core-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0 b5bf70b7e32d7ddd9742cc821d471c5fabd4e3df - jimczi - 2018-09-18 13:07:55]
    at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.createMainIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:257) ~[solr-core-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0 b5bf70b7e32d7ddd9742cc821d471c5fabd4e3df - jimczi - 2018-09-18 13:07:55]
    at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.getIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:131) ~[solr-core-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0 b5bf70b7e32d7ddd9742cc821d471c5fabd4e3df - jimczi - 2018-09-18 13:07:55]
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:2089) ~[solr-core-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0 b5bf70b7e32d7ddd9742cc821d471c5fabd4e3df - jimczi - 2018-09-18 13:07:55]
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:2248) ~[solr-core-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0 b5bf70b7e32d7ddd9742cc821d471c5fabd4e3df - jimczi - 2018-09-18 13:07:55]
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initSearcher(SolrCore.java:1097) ~[solr-core-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0 b5bf70b7e32d7ddd9742cc821d471c5fabd4e3df - jimczi - 2018-09-18 13:07:55]
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:986) ~[solr-core-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0 b5bf70b7e32d7ddd9742cc821d471c5fabd4e3df - jimczi - 2018-09-18 13:07:55]
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:869) ~[solr-core-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0 b5bf70b7e32d7ddd9742cc821d471c5fabd4e3df - jimczi - 2018-09-18 13:07:55]
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1138) ~[solr-core-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0 b5bf70b7e32d7ddd9742cc821d471c5fabd4e3df - jimczi - 2018-09-18 13:07:55]
```

Please provide your valuable solutions.

**Updated:**

**When check in Sitecore logs, below are errors are thrown continuously. But I am able to access the Solr page with IP address or domain URL. In Solr server, Solr service is up and running..**

**Have did Ping and Telnet from Sitecore server to Solr server..That also working fine.**

```
5844 11:31:27 WARN  Error connecting to solr. Solr is not running on the provided url [Url:https://<solr server IP>:8983/solr/]
5844 11:31:27 ERROR Unable to connect to Solr at [https://<solr server IP>:8983/solr/]
Exception: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrConnectors.Exceptions+SolrConnectorException
Message: Unable to connect to Solr at [https://<solr server IP>:8983/solr/]
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrConnectors.SolrConnector.VerifyConnection(String solrAddress)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrConnectors.SolrConnector.Initialize(String solrAddress)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex.InitializeSolr()
```

Comment: Can you check this post? looks like it has the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/55722829/109850

Answer (score 1):

**Issue:**
Indexes are not listed in Indexing Manager.

**Error log:**

```
5844 11:31:27 WARN  Error connecting to solr. Solr is not running on the provided url [Url:https://<solr server URL>:8983/solr/]
5844 11:31:27 ERROR Unable to connect to Solr at [https://<solr server URL>:8983/solr/]
Exception: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrConnectors.Exceptions+SolrConnectorException
Message: Unable to connect to Solr at [https://<solr server URL>:8983/solr/]
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrConnectors.SolrConnector.VerifyConnection(String solrAddress)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrConnectors.SolrConnector.Initialize(String solrAddress)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex.InitializeSolr()
```

**Cause for the issue:**
Forward slash at the end of the Solr URL caused this issue.

```
<add name="solr.search" connectionString="https://<solr server domain URL>:8983/solr/" />
```

**Solution:**

After removed the forward slash at the end of URL, working as champ.

**Correct way to mention Solr URL in connection string.**

```
<add name="solr.search" connectionString="https://index-lablink.ttgtpmg.net:8983/solr" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your index data directory is OK, but with some file missing.

If you delete (or backup) the data directory *(**D:\KPSolr\solr-7.5.0\server\solr_master_index\data** in your case for master index)*, Solr will recreate a new index automatically on startup. Of course it will be empty and you will need to rebuild index to populate it with data.

I hope, you can fix the error just deleting your index data directory and then reindex.

Comment: Thanks..But I can't see the indexes list in Indexing Manager of SItecore control panel. Thats the actual issue. It would be great if you would provide solution for this issue.

Comment: You dont see indices because of cores can not be loaded in Solr due to this error. I think you can`t even see your corrupted indices in Sorl and even more so in Sitecore.

Comment: I hope, you can fix the error just deleting your index data directory and then reindex. -  Can you please let me know how to rebuild indexes if "indexing manager" does not show any indexes

Comment: Hello x3mxray, Please refer the updated question. I am getting exceptions such as Solr is not running with that URL or IP addess. But I am able to access the Solr page using Ip or domain URL. Its looking weird..Any thoughts please?